# Rust - How to Restrict T Inputs to only certain types?

Tags: rust

`UPDATE`

Through gaining a much better understanding of the language, I realised that the issue I had brought up in my question was unrelated to the issue I was encountering.

**The title is still valid however**, and value can still definitely be gained from the responses. Please direct your attention there. Thanks.

---

`Basic Rust Function`

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn calculate <T: Display>(input: T){
where {
    i32: From<T>
}
    --code snip--
    let output = i32::try_from(input)
    --code snip--
}
```

`Error`

```rust
the trait bound `i32: From<&_>` is not satisfied
```

I have a very simple function which takes an input of type T and converts this input into an i32. However, Rust requires me to restrict the inputs to numbers only because it can't convert something like a string into an i32.

It is not immediately clear by reading the documentation how to do this.

Can someone provide a simple and clear explanation of how to implement these restrictions?

Comment: Try this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7141df7c5b76b421197fbe46059af4fc . I'm not Rust expert, but AFAIK, you are not allowed to use generic types as values. It means that `T` generic represents function argument `arg` and if you want to use valud with type `T` please use `arg` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
fn calculate <i32: From<T>,>(...){
```

You've got the right general idea here, but in the angle brackets (generic parameter list), the thing before the colon must *always* be the generic parameter name you're declaring (`T`). When you need to write a trait bound that doesn't work with this syntactic requirement, you use a `where` clause to write the bound separately:

```rust
fn calculate<T>(...)
where
    i32: From<T>
{
```

---

Now, some further suggestions that weren't what you asked about:

1. If you're going to call `try_from`, allowing for fallible conversions, then you should use `TryFrom` in the trait bound, too, so that the caller can actually pass in a type which implements `TryFrom` rather than `From`.
2. Whenever you are *accepting* a type to be converted, you should use `(Try)Into` rather than `(Try)From`. (This is almost entirely the same thing, but it allows slightly more cases.) Conveniently, the reversed type order also removes the need for the `where` clause (though you can still use it if you like it).

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;  // Note: Not necessary in Rust edition 2021

fn calculate<T: TryInto<i32>>(input: T) {
    // ...
    let output = input.try_into();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not clear to me. Are you trying to convert String to i32 or something else?

If you want to convert String to i32 you can just use parse function.

```
fn calculate(args: &str) -> i32 {
  args.parse::<i32>().unwrap()
}
```

Please refer to [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/string.html)